# How to change file URL using FileManager SWIFT

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, firebase-storage

Application records audiofile and uploads it to the Firebase Storage. There is a code of `setupRecorder`

```
func setupRecorder() {
        let format = DateFormatter()
        format.dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
        let currentFileName = "recording-\(format.string(from: Date())).m4a"
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        self.soundFileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(currentFileName)
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: soundFileURL.absoluteString) {
            // probably won't happen. want to do something about it?
        }
        
        let recordSettings: [String: Any] = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue,
            AVEncoderBitRateKey: 128000
        ]
        do {
            recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings)
            recorder.delegate = self
            recorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
            recorder.prepareToRecord()
            recorder.record()// creates/overwrites the file at soundFileURL
        } catch {
            recorder = nil
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

In this block of code I get a `soundFileURL`. Then I use `soundFileURL` to upload to the Firebase Storage.

```
    @IBAction func uploadButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        guard let title = titleRecordTextView.text, title.count > 0 else { return }
        guard let recordURL = soundFileURL else { return }
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
        filename = NSUUID().uuidString
        
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        let recordRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("records/\(uid)").child(filename)
        recordRef.putFile(from: recordURL, metadata: nil) { (metadata, err) in
            print("Record:", recordURL)
            print("Metadata:", metadata)
            
            if let err = err {
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
                print("Failed to upload post :", err)
                return
            }
            
            recordRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed to fetch postUrl:", error)
                    return
                } else {
                    guard let recordUrl = url?.absoluteString else { return }
                    print("Successfully uploaded record:", recordUrl)
                    
                    self.saveToDatabaseWithRecordUrl(recordUrl: recordUrl)
                    self.saveToDatabaseWithRecordUrlSeparately(recordUrl: recordUrl)
                    
                    self.playerStopRecord()
                    self.recordingTimeLabel.text = "00:00"
                    self.stopButton.alpha = 1
                    self.recordButton.isEnabled = true
                    self.recordButton.alpha = 1
                    self.recordingTimeLabel.alpha = 1
                    self.recordingTimeLimitLabel.alpha = 1
                    self.setupPlayingControls()
                    self.addRecordCount()
                    self.titleRecordTextView.resignFirstResponder()
                    self.sourceRecordTextView.resignFirstResponder()
                    self.maxCharacterSourceLabel.text = "\(100)"
                    self.maxCharacterTitleLabel.text = "\(100)"

                    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0

                    self.recordExists = false
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: RecordViewController2.updateFeedNotificationName, object: nil)
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine when I run app the first time, file successfully uploads to the Firebase Storage and user goes to the first ViewController of `TabBarController` by `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0`. When I try to record audiofile again all metadata of the file stays from the first file (I can see it by `print("Metadata:", metadata)`) and doesn't change to new one and there is an error

> Failed to upload post : Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000
> "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response."
> UserInfo={object=records/OLCSOHRmR2dnqDZToW9u0co9hB62/A75ED159-EE32-4F05-827A-38954E79CC71,
> ResponseBody=Can not finalize upload.  Current size is 82613.
> Expected final size is 81355., bucket=....................,
> data={length = 79, bytes = 0x43616e20 6e6f7420 66696e61 6c697a65 ...
> 73203831 3335352e }, data_content_type=text/plain; charset=utf-8,
> NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the
> server response., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus,
> ResponseErrorCode=400}

How to reset all data after leaving ViewController using `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0` and write a new data next time?

Comment: `absoluteString` is not a path. Btw URL has 2 initializers. One for `absoluteString` which contains a scheme `URL(string:)` and another for `path` which doesn't include a scheme and doesn't percent encode the string `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`.

Comment: Note also that you should never reference your files using the whole path. Your app is sandboxed so the location of the file will change every time you launch your app.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. So what should I do to fix it?

Comment: I just said. To check if the file exists use the `path` property of the URL.

Comment: Regarding the location you need to reconstruct the url at the same location using the file name.